# mocking input with a generator

Tags: python, mocking, yield

The following code doesn't do the mocking of input, is there a way to do it with a generator ?

```
    inputlist = [5,1,2,3,4,5,6]

    def mock_input(dummy_prompt=">>> "):
        global inputlist
        for u in inputlist:
                yield str(u)

    __builtins__.input = mock_input

    l=[]
    x= input()
    for u in range(int(x)):
        l.append(int(input()))

    if l==inputlist[1:]:
        print("bravo")
```

The error is x is a generator not a String.

Do i have to create my own generator with a global variable, or i missed something in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a generator to `__builtins__.input` rather than iterating with a generator and returning a value, this is why it doesn't work.

Instead, create a generate with `iter` and iterate over it with `next(..)`

```
inputlist = [6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
gen = iter(inputlist)

def mock_input(dummy_prompt=">>> "):
    return str(next(gen))

__builtins__.input = mock_input

l=[]
x= input()
for u in range(int(x)):
    l.append(int(input()))

if l==inputlist[1:]:
    print("bravo")
```

PS: I modified first number of the list to 6 otherwise you were missing an item and bravo didnt print

Answer (score 1):

Ok thank you i missed the moment where the generator is instantiated.

```
def gg(l):
    for u in l:
            yield str(u)


def mockinput(thelist):
    bob = gg(thelist)
    __builtins__.input = lambda prompt="toto":  str(next(bob))


inputlist = [6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
mockinput(inputlist)

l=[]
for u in range(int(input())):
    l.append(int(input()))
    print(l)

if l==inputlist[1:]:
    print("bravo")
```

So i need to doit in two steps because i don't want any global variables

Comment: If you did not want global variables, you should have precised it initially because my answer is perfectly valid otherwise. And please accept one or the other to close the topic.